# About Grails Service Class Singleton Property

Tags: java, grails

I am a bit confused in Grails Service Class singleton property. As we know Grails Service Class is singleton by default. If it is so, why does it allow to instantiate the class without any error using the new keyword? If we instantiate the service class, does it create the different object on each call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scope of a Grails service is related to how the dependency injection is done by Spring. This scope only impacts injected services.

You are free to instantiate a service class as many times as you want and it does create a new instance every time. The framework doesn't restrict this, nor should it. However, you should stick with relying on dependency injection to access your services.

Answer (score 1):

> If it is so, why does it allow to instantiate the class without any
>   error using the new keyword?

We aren't preventing you from creating an instance, but there is no good reason to ever do that. You should never `new` up an instance of a Grails service class in the app.

> If we instantiate the service class, does it create the different
>   object on each call?

Yes it does, but as stated above you should never create an instance.

Grails Service artifacts are singleton by default and what that means is 1 instance is created and added to the Spring application context.  If you want a reference to the instance you should let Spring inject the instance wherever you need it, not create an instance yourself.